# Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'WARNING'" in <bound method xxx.__del__ of <yyy.xxx object at 0xd08c48c>> ignored

Tags: python, couchdb

First some introduction to my problem: one of my (complex) objects needs to be cleaned up when it is going to be destroyed. The reason is that it has a list of documents which must be eventually sent to a couchdb instance (the list is kept in order to perform bulk writes). If the object is deleted, the list of documents must be sent to the server.

Sending the list to the server is a complicated process: you need to get the current revision  of the documents that you want to update, before actually sending them. Documents could be already present in couchdb, could be deleted, etc. Couchdb is a bit complicated in this regard. I just mention this to make clear that I can not re-implement this functionality just for the sake of solving my problem (see below).

In this process, I rely on some global objects to perform some actions: specifically, I have a module `log` object, as I have in all my code, to perform logging.

And all this action is triggered from the `__del__` method in my class. But when my objects are deleted, I get the error message:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'WARNING'" in <bound method xxx.__del__ of <yyy.xxx object at 0xd08c48c>> ignored
```

Obviously, the module `log` object is not present when the object is being deleted. My questions are:

1. Why are the global objects (in this case module objects) not defined anymore?
2. In what order does python delete global objects? Can I change this order? Can I mark an object as "last to delete"?
3. What can I do to prevent this behavior?

If this can not be changed, I am in a big trouble. The same pattern is in all around my code, where my classes rely in a module `log` object to perform logging, or any other module object. Most of my classes do not implement a `__del__` method, but some do.

Comment: `__del__` is not something that you can rely on being run, especially if run order is important.  The Python docs even say that the state of the executing code should in no way be relied upon when a runtime is being torn down.  However, the fact that your `log` object exists but is `None` (as opposed to non-existent) suggests to me that how and when `__del__` is being called is not the root problem here.  Can you post some code?

Comment: What's the relations between CouchDB and Python in this question? But, anyway, need some code to make things clear.